Why doesn't the following idea prove the statement "If $A_{1}, A_{2}$ are regular languages then so is $A_{1}+A_{2}$"
Theorem
Why doesn't the following idea prove the statement "If $A_{1}, A_{2}$ are regular languages then so is $A_{1}+A_{2}$"(concatenation operation)
Argument
If one designs the automaton for $A_{1}+A_{2}$ by keeping $M_{1}$ first and joining an edge between all the accept states of $M_{1}$ to the start state of $M_{2}$ for every value of the alphabet. That way say $xy$ belongs in $A_{1}+A_{2}$, then $x$ part will be accepted by $M_{1}$ and the latter part will be pushed to $M_{2}$.
The MIT proffessor Michael Sipser says in his lecture that it doesn't work, but I am not able to see why? Kindly help.

Suppose the languages are $X$ and $Y$ and the alphabet is $\Sigma$. The new machine you described recognizes $X\Sigma Y$, not $XY$.

A similar construction does work if the edges you use to join the machines have $\epsilon$-transitions. But automata do not normally allow this.

By "automaton" do you understand the deterministic or nondeterministic variety?  (If the deterministic case, then adding those edges could destroy determinism; and also, as MJD has pointed out, even in the nondeterministic case it wouldn't do the right thing.)

Okay, so you are saying that  the first alphabet of $y$ gets used up to move from $M_{1}$ to $M_{2}$, hence the start state of $M_{2}$ is not being fed the first alphabet, hence it's not anymore necessary for this to get it accepted by $M_{2}$. In essence what goes inside $M_{2}$ is not $y$ but $y^{'}$ which doesn't have first element of $y$.  @MJD. Is it correct?

If I understand you correctly, then yes. I suggest you try an example. Maybe $\Sigma={a,b,c}$ and $X=a^, Y=b^$.

Using + for the concatenation is misleading, since + is usually used for the union. The reason is that $A^*$ with union and concatenation is a semiring.
